# Wrong output with C program

Tags: c

I'm trying to get this code work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 2

typedef struct identite {
    char numClient[20];
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
} Identite;

typedef struct facture {
    int numFacture;
    Identite personne;
    float prix;
    int anlimite;
} Facture;

Facture tabFactures[10];
// initialisation ???

Facture saisirFacture() {
    Facture uneFacture;
    printf("saisissez le numero de la facture: ");
    scanf("%d", &uneFacture.numFacture);
    printf("saisissez le numero du client: ");
    scanf("%s", &uneFacture.personne.numClient);
    printf("saisissez le nom du client: ");
    scanf("%s", &uneFacture.personne.nom);
    printf("saisissez le prenom du client: ");
    scanf("%s", &uneFacture.personne.prenom);
    printf("saisissez le prix: ");
    scanf("%f", &uneFacture.prix);
    printf("saisissez anlimite: ");
    scanf("%d", &uneFacture.anlimite);
    printf("Vous avez renseigné tous les champs, Merci.\n");
    return uneFacture;
}

void saisirTabFacture() {
    int i;
    i = 0;
    Facture fi;
    while (i < N) {
        tabFactures[i] = fi;
        saisirFacture(fi);
        i++;
    }
    getch();
}

void afficheFacture(Facture uneFacture) { 
    printf("le numero de la facture est:%d\n", uneFacture.numFacture);
    printf("le numero du client est:%s\n", uneFacture.personne.numClient);
    printf("le nom du client est:%s\n", uneFacture.personne.nom);
    printf("le prenom du client est:%s\n", uneFacture.personne.prenom);
    printf("le prix est:%f\n", uneFacture.prix);
    printf("annee limite est:%d\n", uneFacture.anlimite);
    getch();
}

void afficheTabFacture() {     
    Facture fi;
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < N - 1;i++) {
        tabFactures[i] = fi
            afficheFacture(tabFactures);
    }
}

int main() {
    Facture tabFactures[N];
    Facture uneFacture;
    printf("la saisie des factures : \n");
    saisirTabFacture();
    printf("les factures qui vous avez saisi sont:");
    afficheTabFacture(tabFactures);

    return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine except the output of the function `afficherTabFacture(tabFactures)`, instead of giving the strings I have entered it gives special characters, or it gives O or empty values. Here is an image:

[image]

Could you please help me to solve it?

Comment: `scanf("%s",uneFacture.personne.numClient);`. It's already a pointer.

Comment: I tried it, no change.

Comment: not sure if this is related to the problem, but it looks like you have some shadowing going on.. there's a global `tabFactures` and a `tabFactures` declared in `main` which is then passed to a function. One of those should go. Also `Facture uneFacture` is unused in `main`.

Comment: There's no way this code can compile. You're missing a `;` at the end of `tabFactures[i]=fi`. And you call `afficheFacture(tabFactures);`. `tabFactures` is an array of `Facture`, but `afficheFacture` expects a single `Facture` argument.

Comment: furthermore `afficheTabFacture` accepts no arguments, yet you are passing it one in `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `saisirFacture` returns a `Facture` by value, but you do not store this return value, instead you pass a `Facture` as an argument in `saisirTabFacture`.
- There is  local array `tabFactures` in `main` and a global variable by the same name: `main` and `saisirTabFacture` are not referring to the same array.
- `afficheTabFacture` should be passed a `Facture` object, not an array of `Facture` objects.

Here is a modified version that will prompt for 2 bills and then print them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define N 2

typedef struct identite {
    char numClient[20];
    char nom[20];
    char prenom[20];
} Identite;

typedef struct facture {
    int numFacture;
    Identite personne;
    float prix;
    int anlimite;
} Facture;

Facture saisirFacture(void) {
    Facture uneFacture;
    printf("saisissez le numero de la facture: ");
    scanf("%d", &uneFacture.numFacture);
    printf("saisissez le numero du client: ");
    scanf("%19s", uneFacture.personne.numClient);
    printf("saisissez le nom du client: ");
    scanf("%19s", uneFacture.personne.nom);
    printf("saisissez le prenom du client: ");
    scanf("%19s", uneFacture.personne.prenom);
    printf("saisissez le prix: ");
    scanf("%f", &uneFacture.prix);
    printf("saisissez anlimite: ");
    scanf("%d", &uneFacture.anlimite);
    printf("Vous avez renseigné tous les champs, Merci.\n");
    return uneFacture;
}

void saisirTabFacture(Facture tabFactures[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tabFactures[i] = saisirFacture();
    }
    getch();
}

void afficheFacture(Facture uneFacture) { 
    printf("le numero de la facture est:%d\n", uneFacture.numFacture);
    printf("le numero du client est:%s\n", uneFacture.personne.numClient);
    printf("le nom du client est:%s\n", uneFacture.personne.nom);
    printf("le prenom du client est:%s\n", uneFacture.personne.prenom);
    printf("le prix est:%f\n", uneFacture.prix);
    printf("annee limite est:%d\n", uneFacture.anlimite);
    getch();
}

void afficheTabFacture(Facture tabFactures[]) {     
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        afficheFacture(tabFactures[i]);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    Facture tabFactures[N];
    Facture uneFacture;
    printf("la saisie des factures : \n");
    saisirTabFacture(tabFactures);
    printf("les factures qui vous avez saisi sont:");
    afficheTabFacture(tabFactures);

    return 0;
}
```